# Lubuntu Lost Display settings after restart

Tags: lubuntu, display, restart

I Installed Lubuntu 
After restart I lost my dual display settings, and I must do this again.
I must deselect one display, change the resolution and then select the second display.
How I can fix it?
Thank You

Comment: Your release of Lubuntu would be helpful (*16.04 LTS & 18.04 LTS use LXDE, 18.10 & later use LXQt and is thus different*)

Comment: My Lubuntu release is 18.04 LTS

Comment: If I had this problem, I would write an xrandr command and set it to run at startup. If this method appeals to you, search the site for xrandr questions, there are plenty.

Comment: I installed Lubuntu two weeks ago. I 'am not programmer. It's too difficult for me. Can you write me step by step where I must go and what I must do, 1......2.....3..........etc? Thank You